# Downvoting or Voting to Close without leaving a comment

Tags: support

Since some time I encountered that people quickly are downvoting or voting to close on questions I pose without leaving any comment. Of course I'm adressing them in the hope to resolve the problem however mostly nothing comes back. But since some time this become already way to much. What should I do?

Comment: For more than you ever wanted to know on this subject read this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: What about voting to close?

Comment: When question is really closed, the reason is displayed in big banner, so better than any comment.

Answer (score 13):

I don't want to be rude but it's probably because you post questions like this, that have been answered millions of time before and that regular users have grown tired of answering. You might want to run a little search before posting content this way, you are sure that the content you are about to post is not already covered somewhere else and therefore, not instantly downvoted.

As Chris said in the comment above, you can refer to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) where the subject has been covered from all possible angles.

That being said, comments are **not mandatory**. They are to the user's discretion. The voting system is anonymous; if user had to post a comment after voting, that would go against that system wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes makes sense that would kind of go against the principle that voting is anonymous. What about the voting to close? Usually I first try to find an unswer by browsing SE - if I don't I ask. But people usually vote as off-topic since it misses context however when I come along a problem I cannot find an answer then I try to post the question as simple as possible. Should I maybe rethink this?

Comment: @Freeze_S It is *Kinda* anonymous too. Is say kinda because the 5 users that contributed to the closing are exposed once the question is, indeed closed. But until that point, it is anonymous. Don't get me wrong, it is *encouraged* to comment if you see something bad in a post but it is not a *problem* if you don't do it.

Comment: Down-voting without leaving a comment is not constructive.